# Should I undelete my answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067144/gcc-optimization-how-can-less-operations-be-slower) another user initially posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fd6b74e5-0cda-4236-ab7f-f00607835582/view-source) that didn't address the problem and it was downvoted. After some (deleted my own comments) discussion and figuring things out I posted an answer that [figured out OP's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f5999278-d82a-4514-9d05-4867f77fa2cb). It wasn't upvoted. Some time after, the other user [edited in](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f51d0837-45cd-4459-987d-51f8ef24e6f7/view-source) essentially what was already in my answer and got accepted by the OP with this comment:

> Thanks that explains it! I should have tried for different gcc parameters before posting.

As it started to accumulate upvotes while mine didn't, I decided to delete my answer. The post now has 6 upvotes.

I find OP's behavior strange given that essentially the answer to the problem was already present in the comments and in my answer, but whatever. Maybe I'm just angry at nothing.

Should I undelete my answer or just cut my losses and move on?

Comment: You *really* **really** mean to undelete a previous version and not the current one, right?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but vandalising your answer  as you did (even while it's deleted) isn't a great look.

Comment: @user6292850 while it's true only 10k+ users can see deleted answers - they still don't want to see **that** - don't do so again in future please.